# Avoid losing POST data when using php pagination

Tags: php, post, get, pagination

I am working on a renting website that transfer date from page to another, for example the user enter a date and some information and when he goes to another page he should find the information that he entered in the first page. Everything works fine except that when I add pagination like this: [1] [2] [3] [4] every time I click on a page number in the pagination the POST data will be lost. For example if I clicked number 2 in the pagination I get this message:

```
Undefined index: date......
```

I found some solutions which is using get method but I don't know how to use get method in this situation.

What should I change to my code to avoid losing POST data?

here is my full code:

```
 <?php
$date= $_POST['date']; // the post data from previous page
$info= $_POST['info']; // the post data from previous page

?>  


<form action="next_page.php" method="post" name="myForm"> 


<input name="date" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" />
<input name="info" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $info; ?>" />




<?php

include(db.php);


$q="select count(*) \"total\"  from users";
$ros1=mysql_query($q,$link);
$row=(mysql_fetch_array($ros1));
$total=$row['total'];
$dis=8;
$total_page=ceil($total/$dis);


$page_cur=(isset($_GET['page']))?$_GET['page']:1;
$k=($page_cur-1)*$dis;

$query="SELECT * FROM cars limit $k,$dis";
$ros=mysql_query($query,$link);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ros))
{

 echo  $row["user_id"];

echo  $row["user_name"];

echo  $row["user_email"];
}
for($i=1;$i<=$total_page;$i++){
if($page_cur==$i){
echo ' <input type="button" value="'.$i.'"> ';
}
else{
echo '<a href="carstype.php?page='.$i.'"> <input type="button" value="'.$i.'"> </a>';
}}
?>
<input  type="submit" name="userId" value="' .$row['user_id'] . '" /> 

</form>
```

Comment: You can store the data in [session](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) variables.

Comment: or put it on the page in input fields and let it be resubmitted

Comment: I think using the session is the more elegant way to do this.

Comment: I would suggest using GET only for non sensitive data, and when data will not exceed say 150 characters, to prevent huge urls.
Using GET only will support the use of multiple tabs in the browser, without out of sync errors you will encouter with SESSION, and reposting is also a possibility. (also will not cause problems with tabs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use GET method instead of POST method.

```
    <?php
$date = $_GET['date']; // the post data from previous page
$info = $_GET['info']; // the post data from previous page
?>  


<form action="next_page.php" method="get" name="myForm"> 


    <input name="date" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" />
    <input name="info" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $info; ?>" />




    <?php
    include(db . php);


    $q = "select count(*) \"total\"  from users";
    $ros1 = mysql_query($q, $link);
    $row = (mysql_fetch_array($ros1));
    $total = $row['total'];
    $dis = 8;
    $total_page = ceil($total / $dis);


    $page_cur = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
    $k = ($page_cur - 1) * $dis;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM cars limit $k,$dis";
    $ros = mysql_query($query, $link);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($ros)) {

        echo $row["user_id"];

        echo $row["user_name"];

        echo $row["user_email"];
    }
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_page; $i++) {
        if ($page_cur == $i) {
            echo ' <input type="button" value="' . $i . '"> ';
        } else {
            echo '<a href="carstype.php?page=' . $i . '&date=' . $date . '&info=' . $info . '"> $i </a>';
        }
    }
    ?>
    <input  type="submit" name="userId" value="' .$row['user_id'] . '" /> 

</form>
```

Comment: I tried get method but it didn't work, it gives the same message Undefined index: after I click a pagination button

Comment: you should also add your GET keys in paginate method.
your link should be for next page like this-

http://example.com/index.php?page=2&date=2014-07-30&info=value_of_info_field

Comment: should I add & between variables

Answer (score 0):

You should store this information somewhere between your http-requests. There are some possible solutions for that:

1. you can store this information in the database
2. in session (temporarily store, if you don't need this data in your database)
3. store in every html page as a hidden field

Comment: how can I store the data in session ?

Comment: It's explained very good here: http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/sessions.shtml . You should start_session() for your user and then you can use array $_SESSION for your variables

Comment: When you make start_session() php will send to the user browser PHPSESSID variable - just a number to identify your user the next time. Next time the browser will make request, php will know which user it is. For each session (user) you can store variables - they are stored in a file on the server side. You can get them in php by using the array $_SERVER.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP sessions to store users input on the server:

[PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Keep all the data in `$_SESSION` and read it from there when it's needed in the page.
Update the stored values when the users inputs something new.

Answer (score 0):

A good way in my opinion is to start the seach with a POST form and if the results exceed a limit then construct pagination links which really are post forms incorporating the search keyword and target page in the form of hidden variables.

Passing the search keyword as a get parameter needs care (url encode) because urls have limits on the characters they allow (ascii letters and digits, and characters such as /, ~, -, _ etc ) for example a user might search for something in japanese or greek or use symbols.

Passing the search keyword as a session variable also needs care. Consider this scenario: a user has opened multiple result pages, but all pages will hereafter have access to the last processed session saved keyword. Also storing the search keyword in a session requires coordination by the developer such as when to destroy the session variable etc.

Comment: It would help if you broke down this text into paragraphs (separated by 2 newlines), it's hard to read as it is.